# Which placeholder should I use in and why?

Tags: c, printf, double, implicit-conversion, conversion-specifier

Why the code only works when I use the %lf or %f place holder (second placeholder), but its printing 0 when I use %d?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{

    long id;
    id = 123456789;
    double Hourly;
    Hourly = 30;
    int HoursAday, daysAweek, Fired, Hired;
    HoursAday = 8; daysAweek = 5; Fired = 2021; Hired = 2019;
    printf("bob, id: \"%d\" should get %lf", id, (Hourly * HoursAday * daysAweek) * (Fired - Hired));
```

Comment: `%d` is for `int` values. `%lf` (and `%f` but only for `printf`) is for `double` values. This should have been explained in any decent book, class or tutorial. Mismatching format specifier and argument value type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: `void main()` should be `int main()`

Comment: You could cast the float value to int, and lose the decimals part (if values are in range of course)

Comment: Why @Kevin? It compiles and returns `0` as expected...

Comment: I wonder why the "In C" was edited out ?? While there is the C tag, reading the question in context is easier to follow.

Comment: @Matthieu: Because C 2018 5.1.2.2.1 1 says “The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no parameters:…” The fact that the compiler you tested with accepted it does not mean that other compilers will, or even that your compiler will accept it with different switches or even that programs with `void main()` other than the one you tried will work.

Comment: @Matthieu See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c. It's more strict in C++, but still in C you should use `int main()` or `int main(int, char**)`

Comment: @Breakingnotsobad: It is redundant when the C tag is present.

Comment: @Kevin: `int main(void)` is shown in the C standard and is preferred, although `int main()` is equivalent in definitions (but not in declarations that are not definitions).

Comment: Even the code as-is already should complain about a formatting mismatch of the *first* argument, let alone the *second*. Compile with warnings enabled. Always.

Answer (score 3):

The type of `(Hourly * HoursAday * daysAweek) * (Fired - Hired)` is `double` so the correct specifier is `%lf`. Because of [variadic arguments default conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments) the code will also work with `%f` (*). But `%d` is undefined behavior.

Also, the correct specifier for `id` (which is of type `long`) is `%ld`. `%d` is undefined behavior.

See the documentation for printf: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

(*) A `float` variadic argument always gets converted to `double`. So the `printf` family of functions will never receive a `float`, they will always receive a `double`. That's why `%f` and `%lf` are for practical reasons equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

This expression

```
(Hourly * HoursAday * daysAweek) * (Fired - Hired)
```

has the type `double` due to the usual arithmetic conversions because the variable `Hourly` has the type `double`. That is if one operand has the type `double` and other operand has an integer type in a binary operation then the operand with the integer type is converted to the type `double`.

Using the wrong conversion specifier `%d` designed to output objects of the type `int` with an object of the type `double` invokes undefined behavior.

Pay attention to that in this conversion specifier `%lf` the length modifier `l` has no effect. So it is enough to use `%f`.